# Unable to build or compile phonegap 2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

System info .
Xcode : 4.3.3
OSX : 10.7.4

I have downloaded phonegap 2.1( incubator-cordova-ios). I have successfully created the project using command line code as mentioned in the docs .

```
$ ./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

I used code like below to build my project.
    $ /path/to/my_new_cordova_project/cordova/debug

When i try to debug, i get error following error

> /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:252:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions' [3]
>            if (&ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions != NULL) {
>                 ^
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:253:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration,3]
>                addrBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
>                           ^
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:253:22:{253:24-253:66}: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'ABAddressBookRef' (aka 'const void *') from 'int' [3]
>                addrBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
>                         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:326:96:{326:96-326:139}{326:109-326:139}: error: cast of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') requires a bridged cast [4]
>                                    CDVContact* xferContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:k]];
>                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:326:97: note: use __bridge to convert directly (no change in ownership) [4]
>                                    CDVContact* xferContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:k]];
>                                                                                                    ^
>                                                                                                    _*bridge 
>   fix-it:"/Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m":{326:97-326:97}:"*_bridge "
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:326:97: note: use __bridge_retained to make an ARC object available as a +1 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') [4]
>                                    CDVContact* xferContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:k]];
>                                                                                                    ^
>                                                                                                    __bridge_retained 
>   fix-it:"/Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m":{326:97-326:97}:"__bridge_retained "
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:338:92:{338:92-338:135}{338:105-338:135}: error: cast of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') requires a bridged cast [4]
>                                CDVContact* testContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:j]];
>                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:338:93: note: use __bridge to convert directly (no change in ownership) [4]
>                                CDVContact* testContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:j]];
>                                                                                                ^
>                                                                                                _*bridge 
>   fix-it:"/Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m":{338:93-338:93}:"*_bridge "
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:338:93: note: use __bridge_retained to make an ARC object available as a +1 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') [4]
>                                CDVContact* testContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)[foundRecords objectAtIndex:j]];
>                                                                                                ^
>                                                                                                __bridge_retained 
>   fix-it:"/Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m":{338:93-338:93}:"__bridge_retained "
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:560:21:{560:23-560:67}: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'ABAddressBookRef' (aka 'const void *') from 'int' [3]
>            addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
>                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/virtusa3/pgt/myproject1/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:562:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration,3]
>            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
>            ^
>   4 warnings and 3 errors generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to this issue reported by others building on Snow Leopard with older versions of Xcode:
[Running ./cordova/debug / cordova/emulate causes errors"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1597)

It seems that there are plans to fix it but updating to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.51 will fix it. It did for me.